# Find coordinates of barcode in image c#

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I have some images which contains 3-4 bar codes. I want to mark all the bar codes irrespective of the position. I'm trying to get all the rectangles in the images using below code, but they return empty or do not mark the bar codes. Am I missing something? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

[I also tried to follow this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/) and tried to port it to EmguCV and was not sure what to pass for missing params of certain functions. Commented part are the ones which I'm not sure. Please guide me to correct direction.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.IO;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {

       //public static Mat mat = new Mat();
       // public static Mat kernel = new Mat();

       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> gradX = mat.ToImage<Bgr,byte>();
       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> gradY = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> gradient = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> blur = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> thresh = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
       // private static Image<Bgr, byte> closed = mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                    Image<Bgr, byte> gambar = new Image<Bgr, byte>("source.jpg");
                    Image<Bgr, byte> kotak = detectBarcode(gambar);
                    kotak.ToBitmap().Save("destination.jpg");

            Console.ReadKey();

        }


        private static Image<Bgr, byte> detectBarcode(Image<Bgr, byte> image)
        {

            try
            {
                Image<Gray, byte> imageGrey = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();



                //CvInvoke.Sobel(imageGrey, gradX, DepthType.Cv32F, 1, 0, -1);
                //CvInvoke.Sobel(imageGrey, gradY, DepthType.Cv32F, 0, 1, -1);

                //CvInvoke.Subtract(gradX, gradY, gradient);
                //CvInvoke.ConvertScaleAbs(gradient, gradient, 0, 0);

                //CvInvoke.Blur(gradient, blur, new System.Drawing.Size(new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9)), new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9));
                //CvInvoke.Threshold(blur, thresh, 255, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);

                //kernel = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Rectangle, new System.Drawing.Size(new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9)), new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9));

                //CvInvoke.MorphologyEx(thresh,closed,MorphOp.Close,kernel,);

                //CvInvoke.Erode(closed,closed, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0),4,BorderType.Default,);
                //CvInvoke.Dilate(closed, closed, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), 4, BorderType.Default,);

                List<RotatedRect> boxList = new List<RotatedRect>();

                UMat cannyEdges = new UMat();
                double cannyThreshold = 180.0;
                double cannyThresholdLinking = 120.0;
                CvInvoke.Canny(imageGrey, cannyEdges, cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);


                using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint countours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                {

                    CvInvoke.FindContours(cannyEdges, countours, null, RetrType.List,
                    ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
                    int count = countours.Size;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        using (VectorOfPoint kontur = countours[i])
                        using (VectorOfPoint approxContour = new VectorOfPoint())
                        {
                            CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(kontur, approxContour, CvInvoke.ArcLength(kontur, true) * 0.05, true);
                            if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(approxContour, false) > 250) //only consider contours with area greater than 250
                            {
                                if (approxContour.Size == 4) //rectangle
                                {
                                    //determine if allthe angles in the contour are within [80,100] degree
                                    bool isRectangle = true;
                                    System.Drawing.Point[] pts = approxContour.ToArray();
                                    LineSegment2D[] edges = Emgu.CV.PointCollection.PolyLine(pts, true);

                                    for (int j = 0; j < edges.Length; j++)
                                    {
                                        double angle = Math.Abs(
                                        edges[(j + i) % edges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(edges[j]));
                                        if (angle < 80 || angle > 100)
                                        {
                                            isRectangle = false;
                                            break;
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (isRectangle) boxList.Add(CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(approxContour));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Image<Bgr, byte> triRectImage = image.Copy();

                foreach (RotatedRect box in boxList)
                    triRectImage.Draw(box, new Bgr(0, 0, 0), 5);
                return triRectImage;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

                return null;
            }



        }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really think all the commented out code adds anything useful to this question? The "minimal" in [mcve] is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

[I find myself referring you to, for example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.3.0/document/html/97b39aab-3ccd-ecd8-4183-6256eaaacfa9.htm)

> public static void Sobel(IInputArray src ,IOutputArray dst,
>   DepthType ddepth, int xorder, int yorder, int kSize = 3, double scale = 1,    double delta = 0,   BorderType borderType =
>   BorderType.Reflect101 )

There follows a detailed list of the parameters and what they mean. If you don't actually understand any of this then I would suggest you [need to read the tutorials](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) thoroughly because otherwise you will need an expert in Emgu CV to tell you how to write your program, which isn't exactly the point of this site.

I don't wish to sound unkind but you at least need to have a stab at whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure! Thanks Kevin.